# Does web scraper package have a limit or something else?

Tags: flutter

I want to fetch the data of products from popular websites like amazon by using [web scraper package](https://pub.dev/packages/web_scraper). Actually, I fetched data from some websites. There was no error. I fetched data from 3 different websites. However, when I changed the website to fetch more data from another website. I can't fetch data anymore. I tried another website and I can't fetch data again.

I searched somethings about web scraping that some people say some websites can block web scraping on their websites.

Comment: A package can;t have limits, maybe the site you are trying has limits....

Comment: it was my fault thank you for your comment